# How to do "ngIf localstorage" data binding

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 application, it has a side menu, located in `app.html`.

If the user is not logged in, he should see in the menu, the login `ion-button`. If the user is logged in, the login button should disappear and instead, he should see the logout button and a protected `example` page.

`login.ts`

```
     onLogin() {
    console.log(this.username, this.password);
    this.authProvider.postLogin(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      localStorage.setItem('wpIonicToken', JSON.stringify(data));
      if (localStorage.getItem('wpIonicToken')) {
        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
      }
    });
  }
 }
```

`app.htm`

```
<div *ngIf="token==true">
      <ion-buttons class="log-out" end>
        <button ion-button text-lowercase icon-right clear menuClose (click)="logout()">
          Logout
          <ion-icon color="grayColor" name="ios-log-out" large></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="token==false">
      <ion-buttons class="log-out" end>
        <button ion-button text-lowercase icon-right clear menuClose (click)="goTo('LoginPage')">
          Login
          <ion-icon color="grayColor" name="ios-log-in" large></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </div>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
token: boolean = false;
if (localStorage.getItem('wpIonicToken')) {
  this.token = true;
}
else {
  this.token = false;
}
  logout() {
  localStorage.clear();
  this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
  }
```

The problem is that, when the user login or logout, `token` is not getting updated unless I refresh the browser, hence the items stay in the menu, when refreshing the browser, the menu gets updated.

Comment: You need to redirect after log in process. For now you only do redirection in constructor

Comment: @David I updated my question, fixed some things, please read the last 2 sentences

Comment: You need some kind of notification mechanism based on observable so that app.ts and other components are notified when the status changes. Otherwise, the value is only retrieved once and never updated

Comment: @David can I make `token` an `ngModel`? I've never done `ngIf ngModel` before so I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

**login.ts**

```
onLogin() {
console.log(this.username, this.password);
this.authProvider.postLogin(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  localStorage.setItem('wpIonicToken', JSON.stringify(data));
  if (localStorage.getItem('wpIonicToken')) {
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);

  }

   this.messageService.broadcast('tokenChanged', {data: data}); //<== add this
});
  }
 }
```

**app.ts**

```
token: boolean = false;

constructor(private messageService: MessageService){
this.messageService.myAppEvent$.subscribe(ev => {
  if (ev.type == 'tokenChanged')
  {
    this.token = ev.data;
  }
});
}
//...

  logout() {
   this.messageService.broadcast('tokenChanged', {data: null});
  this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
  }
```

With the messaging service being defined like this

```
export class MyAppEvent
{
  type: string;
  data: any;
}


@Injectable()
export class MessageService
{
  private myAppEventSubject: Subject<MyAppEvent> = new Subject<MyAppEvent>();
  public readonly myAppEvent$: Observable<MyAppEvent> = this.myAppEventSubject.asObservable();

  broadcast(name: string, data)
  {
    this.myAppEventSubject.next( {type: name,   data: data });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **`this.nav?`** here. You can directly use **`router.navigate`**

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

  logout() {
     this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
     localStorage.clear();
  }
```

Comment: I updated my question, fixed some things, please read the last 2 sentences. As for navigation, it's no big deal, ionic has `navCtrl`, no need for angular router.

Comment: Sorry id d not realise it was ionic

Comment: which order sir?

Comment: It didn't work, i need an observable, like an ng-if ngmodel, but I don't know how to do that